# For a Xamarin Forms application is the PCL architecture becoming obsolete?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms application that uses shared code.  It has three projects, shared, iOS and Android. These are very similar to those which are created when I create a sample application from the Xamarin new project menu.

I am looking to have the application updated and published by a company that has experience in doing this but I am not sure I understand a couple of the work items that have been suggested to me:

- Currently, architecture is PCL which is becoming
  obsolete.
- Move to .NET standards

Could someone explain to me what these work items might mean?

Comment: What cannot you find from Xamarin documentation site? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/code-sharing

Comment: Also, please mark answers as an answer to your question if it helped please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will become obsolete at some point. .NET Standard is the evolvement of the PCL libraries.

With PCL libraries you could target a number of platforms and only the functionality that was supported for **all** targeted platforms were available to you. Associated with each combination of platforms were the profiles. A profile was identified by two or three digits. Notable ones for Xamarin were 111 or 259. Read more on PCLs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/pcl

.NET Standard is a specification of the APIs associated to it. If a platform supports a certain version of the .NET Standard, you are guaranteed that all APIs are available. This way, you can simply target a specific .NET Standard version and each platform that supports it will support your application. The .NET Standard specification has gained a lot of traction and is already more cross-platform than a PCL ever was. Most of the creators of NuGet packages are supporting it already and also Xamarin/Microsoft has replaced the PCL with a .NET Standard library in their templates. Read more on .NET Standard as a concept here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

So, if you have the possibility it might be wise to start moving to the .NET Standard library. That is, if you want to keep supporting your app and need new libraries coming in. If your app is fine the way it is, you can probably keep going with the PCL for a while. Converting is basically: change the csproj structure to the new structure. Retarget your library to netstandard and reinstall all the libraries you have installed, this time to download the .NET Standard compatible version. The last step might be a bit of a pain.

A good resource on converting might be this by Adam Pedley: https://xamarinhelp.com/upgrade-pcl-net-standard-class-library/

There is also a solution to do it automatically: https://smellyc0de.wordpress.com/2018/03/23/automatically-converting-pcl-to-net-standard-2-0-project/

Answer (score 1):

.Net Standard is a specification for a set of APIs. and is the way things are going. With it, comes a higher level of range of .Net SDK APIs you can use, plus most 3rd party Nuget packages will support it. They can support a wider range of platforms. by targeting .Net Standard. Thus you will get access to a larger number of nuget packages. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

I put my Forms Apps into a .Net Standard library, because it easier to unit test. There is a Xamarin Forms nuget package you can use for testing, which means a lot of UI paths can be verified in code, where previously you had to do it on a device, perhaps with automated testing. https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/Xamarin.Forms.Mocks

Upgrading an existing PCL project to .net standard is a pain. Any more, I just create a new Xamarin Forms solution with the same name/root namespace, with the app as .Net Standard, then copy files over.