# Debugging PCL in .NET 7 Android Application in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2022

I have Visual Studio 2022 installed and I'm trying to migrate an old Xamarin.Android project to a .NET 7 Android application. I have successfully installed all NuGet packages, but I'm encountering a problem with the Portable Class Library (PCL) that I share between the iOS and Android projects. It simply doesn't hit the breakpoints in it.

I have no trouble debugging it in the Xamarin.Android project with "fast deployment" turned on, but I cannot get it to debug while debugging the .NET 7 Android application. I've tried changing every setting, but it just doesn't work.

How can I solve this issue and successfully debug my PCL while debugging my .NET 7 Android application in Visual Studio 2022?

Tried all settings configuration

Comment: Have you tried to set your Linker Behavior of Android project: *None/Don't Link*?

Comment: PCL is old obsolete library type.  You can migrate the PCL to a .NET Standard library to see if can debug it. PCL is old tech that likely can't target .NET 5/6/7. In addition, you can refer to this case: [For a Xamarin Forms application is the PCL architecture becoming obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250377/for-a-xamarin-forms-application-is-the-pcl-architecture-becoming-obsolete).